# Pack manager of tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have written this code in python 2.7 and i have used "pack_propagate" in this code. First time "pack_propagate" works fine but when i click on the button 1, "pack_propagate" doesn't work. can anyone tell me the reason?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("pack_forget check")

tk_window_width = 500
tk_window_height = 300
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
x = (screen_width/2) - (tk_window_width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (tk_window_height/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' %(tk_window_width, tk_window_height, x, y))

frame1 = Frame(root, bg="red", height=250, width=250)
frame2 = Frame(root, bg="green", height=250, width=250)

def first():
    frame1.pack(side=TOP, padx=20, pady=20)
    frame1.pack_propagate(0)
    frame2.pack_forget()

def second():
    frame2.pack(side=TOP, padx=20, pady=20)
    frame2.pack_propagate(0)
    frame1.pack_forget()   

label1 = Label(frame1, text="Frame 1")
label1.pack(side="top")
button1 = Button(frame1, text="button 1", command=second, width=10)
button1.pack(side="bottom")

label2 = Label(frame2, text="Frame 2")
label2.pack(side="top")
button2 = Button(frame2, text="button 2", command=first, width=10)
button2.pack(side="bottom")

frame1.pack(side=TOP, padx=20, pady=20)
frame1.pack_propagate(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @AnupamYadav what do you mean "is not working correctly"? What do you expect to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: "pack_propagate" does not shrinks the frame. first time frame1 did not shrink because of pack_propagate but after clicking the "button1", when second frame appears, it does not follow "pack_propagate" even though i have used "pack_propagate" for second frame as well.

Comment: @AnupamYadav ok, currently, when I press `button 1` a green frame is not appearing, do you intend the green frame to appear?

Comment: yes dear. @officialaimm

Comment: calling `pack_propagate` is rarely the correct solution to a problem. If you could better describe what you're actually trying to accomplish, we could come up with some better ideas.

Comment: i want that my frame size should not be shrink if i add less content in frame. @BryanOakley

Comment: The first question I would ask is "why?". I get that there are times when that makes sense, but there are usually better ways  to accomplish that. the problem with `pack_propagate` is that it prevents tkinter from doing something it's really, really good at, which is to make your gui the best size. Turning that off means your program probably won't respond well to the user changing the window size, or if you run the program on a machine with different resolutions or different fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before the mainloop(), it seems to solve the problem. Honestly, I am unsure how it works, but looks like it does. I saw you did that with `frame1` and I was like: hey, why not `frame2`? :D

```
frame2.pack(side=TOP, padx=20, pady=20)
frame2.pack_propagate(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks. its working. I have added "pack_propagate" inside the function.